# How to use GROUP BY in Sequelize and Node

Tags: sequelize.js

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id) as countVolunteer, volunteer_type_id 
FROM `red_cross_vvts`
GROUP BY volunteer_type_id;
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
red_cross_vvts.findAll({
  attributes: ['volunteer_type_id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'volunteer_id'), 'countVolunteer']],
  group: ['volunteer_type_id'],
});
```